# create new column and set increment by step of 3 rows

Tags: mysql

I have table1, i want get table2 ? increment by step of 3 rows.
I want create same |B value for first 3 rows, then increment +1 for second's 3 rows

table1

```
ID  |A      
1    125  
2    412   
3    567  
4    567   
5    485    
6    458    
7    656     
8    856     
9    456
```

table2

```
ID  |A     |B    
1    125   101    
2    412   101 
3    567   101   
4    567   102
5    485   102
6    458   102
7    656   103
8    856   103
9    456   103
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  You tagged multiple...

Comment: Umm... MySQL, SQL Server _and_ Excel? Looking for 3 different answers?

Comment: looking for three method (Mysql /MSSQL and excel)

Comment: You need to be able to do this same thing in all 3 places? Wouldn't it make more sense to capture this information in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can use something like this:

```
SET @c := -1; 
SELECT id, A, (@c := @c+1) DIV 3 + 101 AS B FROM table1
```

You can use either create table from select or insert from select.

Comment: thank you, it work well  (9 rows created in 0.0003 sec

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using MySql's mathematical functions, e.g.:

```
select t.id, t.a, 101 + floor((@rn:=@rn+1)/3) as B
from temp t, (SELECT @rn:=-1) t2;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d678/2/0).

Comment: thank you, it work well  (9 rows created in 0.0005 sec)